# Using `R` and `readr` to handle times without hours

Tags: r, datetime, readr

I have several spreadsheets that I plan to import using `readr`. Times in the original spreadsheet were recorded as minutes and seconds without hours - "0:10" for "M:S". For the beginning timestamps, another leading zero was not used, which I believe is the source of the problem.

Trying a sample with `read_csv`, this column was correctly parsed as time, but with an incorrect format ("H:M"). Using `col_types = cols(timecode = col_time(format = "%M:%S"))` in the call did not seem fix it.

Reprex using a vector as times and `parse_time`:

```
library(tidyverse)

times <- c("0:00", "0:10", "0:53", "6:22", "9:45", "10:21")
parse_time(times) #Shows H:M:S
parse_time(times, format = "%M:%S") #Errors until 10:21
```

What steps can I take to properly import time with only minutes and seconds?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to come from the missing leading zero on the minutes. One solution would be to add the missing zero, and then parsing works properly:

```
library(tidyverse)

times2 <- c("00:00", "00:10", "00:53", "06:22", "09:45", "10:21")
parse_time(times2, format = "%M:%S")
```

Another solution is to use the `strptime` function in base `R`, which can handle the current format. This stores the results as `POSIXlt` objects with extra information though (meaning printing is messier).

In `?parse_time` it indicates that the format specification must match the complete string.

Comment: You could use `strptime` to get mm:ss, then `strftime` to go back to a character vector, stripping off the POSIX class

Comment: `strftime(strptime(times2, format= "%M:%S"), format = "%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: But depending on what OP is trying to do, the POSIX class may be useful.